# Cassandra status changing from active(running) to active(exited) without any errors

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Cassandra does not show any error while running `sudo service cassandra start` but when `sudo service cassandra status` is checked, it shows active(exited). Tried stopping the service and starting again but encountered with the same error.
Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Cassandra version : 2.2.5

cqlsh version : 5.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked in the system.log file and see if any errors are being written?  (/var/log/cassandra/system.log).  If so can you post them?

Comment: Thank you for the response. There are no errors written into the log file. Still confused about how to get this working.

Comment: Can you try turning up the logging level and see if anything shows up.  You can use the `nodetool setlogginglevel` command. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSetLogLev.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I got it working. The problem was that java was not rightly installed and also datastax Cassandra was not installed. After these two problems were solved, Cassandra started working and showed the status as active.